# setError on EditText hides the keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

On Android, I have an `EditText` in which I'm using `setError()` to show an error if the text doesn't pass a validation.

When the error `popup` is shown the keyboard is hidden. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: can you share a screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overwriting the keyboard Ime option with

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            validateText()
        }
        false
}
```

but `false` allowed Android to proceed with the default behaviour of hiding the keyboard, changed it to `true` and it didn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if the text doesn't pass a validation, show an error like below.

```
EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
EditText.requestFocus();
EditText.setError("Your Error Text");
```

Still keyboard is visible on `setError`

[image]